# How to remove symlinks created after a specific date?

Tags: command-line, unix, filesystem, catalina, symlink

Say I did a

```
ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/* /usr/local/include/
```

Now I regret it. How can I delete all these links? The good news is I created them today, so can I filter on the creation date of these symlinks?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [How to delete files from a specific date?](https://www.unix.com/unix-desktop-questions-and-answers/186615-how-delete-files-specific-date.html):

```
# Create a marker
touch -t 201910190000.00 /tmp/PID$$.marker1

# View the files you would like to delete
find /usr/local/include/ -type l -newer /tmp/PID56680.marker1 -ls | less

# Delete them
find /usr/local/include/ -type l -newer /tmp/PID56680.marker1 | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: It might be important to know which symlinks couldn‘t be removed so you probably are better off without the `-f` option.

Comment: Doesn't `find` have a `-delete` operator instead of using `xargs` and `rm`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure you only remove the symlinks created you can run

```
cd /usr/local/include
rm $(cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/; echo *)
```

This does *not* work if the filenames contain spaces etc., but for this specific case this isn't an issue.